# Printing logs (of the running website) in VSCode console

Tags: django, debugging, logging

hi all I have a web built with django framework and running with apache now. I am trying to print() but nothing is shown on the console, so I turned to logger and no luck still.

This is one of my log I tried to print in the view.py, and I was expecting 'helloworld' could be shown on my console...

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info('helloworld')
```

is there anything i should be setting elsewhere? kindly help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely clear. You ran the print() command and nothing printed in the console? You could also try running the code from the terminal to see if it prints there.

My guess is that the line of code executing the print command wasn't actually executed.

Comment: thanks but the terminal in VScode is showing nothing, i started the apache by 'sudo service apache2 restart' in the same terminal. 
the line of code is just placed in my first line of Class PostListView(ListView){ ... }

Comment: But are you able to run the app outside of VScode and output print() statements? I'm trying to determine if the problem is resulting from VScode or your Python code

Comment: the web is running on google cloud vm with apache, so how can i monitor the output other than VSCode? I am very new to django ..., after it deploy to the web, seems I cannot do any print()

Comment: But can you also able to run the app locally? It's much easier to debug locally. I'm trying to determine if the print() statements are actually executing.